# Get a 404 error from existing controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http-status-code-404

My asp.net core project controllers working smoothly when i request on localhost or hosted ip.But when I call with domain, I get 404 error.I couldn't find the reason. I'm sure it's not a code error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your IIS bindings are not correct. Can you show the binding for your site in IIS Manager?

Comment: I don't think it's about that. Because it works when I browse in IIS  and with server ip. Only have this problem when I try with domain.

Comment: Yes, that will happen if your bindings are not correct. Do you have another site hosted on the same server?

Comment: How did you configure the domain in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

For resolving domain name, you could follow steps below:

Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` -> Edit `hosts` -> Append `xxx.xx.xx.xx www.test.com` to the end of `hosts` file.